# Simulate user click on anchor tag with jQuery from console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate a user click on a button (from the console) and I can't get anything to work.

First, visit [chegg.com](http://chegg.com) (using Chrome). Next, inspect the page elements and toggle the device so that Chrome's mobile device simulator opens (we need the mobile site).

I want to click on the hamburger menu (three stacked lines) using jQuery but nothing I enter into the console will do that **(the solution must work from the console)**. The element looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="More ..." class="nav icon More">Navigate</a>
```

Initially I thought that the `href="javascript:;"` that was causing the problem (I realize that normally it shouldn't but I was grasping at straws), but after doing some testing it doesn't seem that like that's the case.

I have tried the following:

```
$('a.nav.icon.More').click()
$('a.nav.icon.More')[0].click()
$('a.nav.icon.More').trigger() // returns error
$('a.nav.icon.More').mousedown()
```

I have also tried clicking on the parents element(s) in case the event listener was attached to one of those, but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does $('a.nav.icon.More').length returns???

Comment: I don't see the hamburger when I switch to the mobile site, and `$('a.nav.icon.More')` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It returns 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird problem indeed. All of the usual ways to click don't work, as you've noticed. I'm surprised at the "answers" posted here since it's clear from just trying them that none of them work for this site you've linked.

Looking at the source code, it appears the site's JS does some strange things with event binding in a non-traditional way (for example, the show/hide menu event is bound to `hamburger` on an `ns.CLICK` event instead of a traditional `click` event). There is also the strangeness of my browser's forward and back buttons changing whenever I click and re-click the menu manually, making me think something is strange with the way routing and history is implemented.

So, you're not going crazy:) I can't think of an easy way to trigger the click on the site, but from the JS we can also see that the click event is equivalent to toggling the `hidden` class from `ExtendedNav`. So if you want an equivalent of the action the click would do, you can call `$('.ExtendedNav').toggleClass('hidden')`.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the way to go. Thanks for the help, if nothing more than a sanity check!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="more-item nav-item active">
    <div class="header">More <span class="arrow-down"></span></div>
    <div class="carrot">
        <div class="carrot-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-hover-content hover-box">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.chegg.com/signup/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F" class="track-signup">Create an account</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.chegg.com/login/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F" class="track-signin hide-initially">Sign in</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.chegg.com/login/?redirect=/my/account/returnbooks" class="track-returnbooks" data-noajax="">Return your books</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.chegg.com/sell-textbooks" class="track-selltextbooks" data-noajax="">Sell your books</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.chegg.com/contactus" class="track-help" data-noajax="">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div
```

You must call click on container  tag a

try this

```
$(".more-item.nav-item").click()
```

Comment: You're looking at the desktop site. I need this to work on the mobile site, as stated in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is one of the best options. But, you should pass the event as the parameter:

```
$('a.nav.icon.More').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Yes, I should have added that as another option that I tried previously, but that didn't work either.